# Battery drains very rapidly on my phone (Oppo F1). What could be the reason? (Please read details before answering)

Tags: battery

There are no apps running in the background (I recently factory reset it, no third party apps have been installed except one or two; and I am sure they are not the ones draining battery) and I have tried replacing the battery too; but the drain is 5℅ per hour when the phone is idle. The network signal is strong all time. I have never faced such issues earlier.

The phone is around 2 years old and the new battery is 3 days old. The new battery is genuine. Even the older battery (genuine) is perfectly alright, I know that.

Every app that I use drains up lot of battery, say for instance I use Calculator for 5 minutes, Whatsapp for 2 minutes (making sure that after using they do not keep running in the background) and Chrome browser for 5 minutes, battery drain will be: for Calculator 25%, Whatsapp 20%, Chrome 30℅.
What could be the reason for such an issue?

Comment: Although you seem to be having issues with battery life, nothing in your question sounds unusual or odd, except the 5%/hr drain. There is no usable information in your question to determine an answer at all. Try installing GSAM Battery Monitor, enabling enhanced reporting if possible, and run it through a cycle of 100% to least 30% a couple times and include screenshots of the main screens in GSAM. Android has the statistics in itself to determine the cause, you just need something to interpret them.

Comment: I get that, but something is draining it and that is what GSAM can help you determine... The cause of the unusual drain. It isn't to test the battery.